# What does it mean for one geometrical axiom to be considered _equivalent_ to another geometrical axiom?

Tags: logic, axiom

What does it mean for one geometrical axiom to be considered *equivalent* to another geometrical axiom?

For example consider Playfair`s axiom:

*In a plane, given a line and a point not on it, at most one line parallel to the given line can be drawn through the point.*

This is always described as being equivalent to Euclid's parallel postulate (the 5th postulate) which states:

*If a line segment intersects two straight lines forming two interior angles on the same side that sum to less than two right angles, then the two lines, if extended indefinitely, meet on that side on which the angles sum to less than two right angles.*

However in Euclidean geometry two points are required to define a line. Therefore I would argue Playfair's axiom is not logically equivalent to Euclid's fifth postulate since it posits the existence of lines through a single point. Playfair's axiom is often characterized as a more streamlined version of Euclid's postulate but I suspect this is because it tacitly uses ideas that are not present in Euclidean geometry.

Often when mathematicians talk about Euclidean geometry I have found they are actually talking about another geometry which was devised to serve as a rationale for non-Euclidean geometry. The claim is basically this: Euclidean geometry = Neutral geometry plus the parallel postulate. However the right side of this "equation" incorporates ideas that are not present in Euclidean geometry.

Comment: That, form the with others Euclid's axioms plus Ax-1 we can prove Ax-2 and vice versa.

Comment: Two points uniquely identify a single line. Through a point, we can draw an infinity of lines.

Comment: See [Parallel postulate: Equivalent properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate#Equivalent_properties)

Comment: In Euclidean geometry a straight line is constructed by first specifying two points. We _can_ draw an infinity of lines through one point but that way of making lines is  inconsistent with the rules of Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Agreed... I'll rewrite it: see [Bk.I Prop.I](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI1.html): through a given point we can draw more than one line.

Comment: Is that the right link?

Comment: Through a point, we can draw more than one line. But a second point is needed. You can't start at the point without knowing where to go.

Comment: I guess the number of lines doesn't matter. The claim that we *can* draw any line through one point is inconsistent with Euclid.

Comment: @Methadont, well said.

Comment: If this principle is not present in Neutral geometry, it is false to say Neutral geometry + the parallel postulate is equivalent to Euclidean geometry.

Comment: @EuclidLookedOnBeautyBare I like the painting by Max Ernst, Euclid.

Comment: @Methadont Thanks. Max Ernst is one of my favourite painters of the 20th century.

Comment: The popular idea that a flat manifold is "equivalent" to Euclidean geometry is grossly mistaken.

Comment: The phrase non-Euclidean geometry is confusing and misleading. It is the study of various types of manifolds. These are not geometries. There is only one formal system that deserves the name "geometry". Geo-metry (the measure of the Earth) is a practice with a theory.

Comment: If the theory of Euclidean geometry is deficient for the practice of geometry, then any improvements to the theory should result from practical needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your error lies in this assertion:

```
However in Euclidean geometry two points are required to define a line.
```

What the axiom actually says is a 'line' (modern interpretation: a line segment) CAN be drawn between two points.  It does NOT say that you HAVE TO HAVE two points before you can draw a line.  In point of fact, you can draw a line entirely without regards to any points, if you so wish.  It is merely useless to do so, as then there is no logical connection between the drawn line and the rest of the figure, so no logical deductions can be applied to it (unless this is the first part of the figure drawn, and other parts are subsequently drawn in relation to it).

Comment: Yes one is free to draw such lines. The problem is mathematicians have given themselves the license to make logical connections between such lines and the rest of the figure.

Comment: In other words if logical connections are to be made a line first needs to be specified by two points.

Comment: If I committed an "error", it is one of tone rather than of logic.

Comment: You *need* at least two points to draw a line. In fact you need infinitely many. There is no error. So two points are required.

Comment: @Methadont I think what Euclid meant by a straight line is more like a string drawn taut between two points rather than a line drawn on a plane surface. Points can be assigned to such a line like beads on a necklace but the line itself is not made of the points. Circles on the other hand are described on a surface with a string of fixed length.

Instructional video: "How to use a string line" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Eto9MJa67A

Comment: Over 2000 years Geo-metry (the measure of the Earth) became confused with drafting. Euclid's Elements was originally a theory of the practice of Geo-metry.

Comment: I recently learned that the words compass of straightedge do not appear anywhere in Euclid's Elements. This tells me that what can be done on a drafting board should not be used to decide what can be done in Euclidean geometry. I also think it was the mathematics of drafting, rather than Euclidean geometry itself, which opened the door to the development of the so called non-Euclidean geometries.